# How to create a view that shows a Managing User all content of their members?

Tags: 7, views

I want to create a View that lists all content of authors who have the same value (text) as the viewing user. Actually they are members and the viewing user is the manager of the members. I have 2 profile fields that I think could be used to show the desired results:

1) an entity reference field called "field_ca_reference" to allow a member to reference a manager

2) a text field is set upon member verification that has the exact same value on both the member and the manager

How do I set up this view such that the manager sees all content of their members only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create a view of all content.

Next, add a relationship to the author of the content. Call the relationship author. Check 'require this relationship'.

Next, add a contextual filter on the entity reference field to the manager, using the author relationship. Under 'When the filter is not available' select 'Provide a default value', and choose 'User ID from logged in user'.

Let me know if it works for you.

I've added an image of my view for you:

[image]

And here is an export of my view - you should be able to import this and it will just work:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'test';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Test';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Test';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'node';
/* Relationship: Content: Author */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Contextual filter: User: CA reference (field_ca_reference) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_ca_reference_target_id']['id'] = 'field_ca_reference_target_id';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_ca_reference_target_id']['table'] = 'field_data_field_ca_reference';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_ca_reference_target_id']['field'] = 'field_ca_reference_target_id';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_ca_reference_target_id']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_ca_reference_target_id']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_ca_reference_target_id']['default_argument_type'] = 'current_user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_ca_reference_target_id']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_ca_reference_target_id']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_ca_reference_target_id']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'test';
```

Comment: Thank you @gillarf. I believe I have followed your instructions exactly as described but it doesn't show any content. If I take away the contextual filter I see all content. FYI: the relationship shows "Content: Content author".

Comment: I just noticed you are using Drupal 7. I'll check to see if there are any differences in 7 from 8.

Comment: I just tested it and it worked fine @bassplaya - stupid question, but when you are testing, are you logged in as the manager user? 

If I were you i'd remove the contextual filter and add the field_ca_reference to the fields, so you can check you are seeing the right value for the manager user via your relationship. If you are, then you just need to get the contextual filter right.

Comment: I've added an image of my view for you.

Comment: Yes! It works. I appreciate your help. Thank you!